# How to force comma in URL using Codeigniter, Javascript and GET form

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, url, get

I want a URL using Codeigniter that is like this:

```
example?type=1,2,3,4
```

I can manually type this in and also navigate to URLs like this and the system works OK. However, I have a form using GET where I want to post multiple values for type. I'm using Javascript to join the inputs.

```
<form action="example" method="GET" id="type-form">
    <select multiple="multiple" name="_type[]" id="type-array-id-1">
        <option value="1">Type 1</option>
        <option value="2">Type 2</option>
        <option value="3">Type 3</option>
        <option value="4">Type 4</option>
        <option value="5">Type 5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type-comma-sep"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Get" />
</form>
<script>
    $("#type-form").bind("submit",function(){
        var type_array = $("#type-array-id-1").val().join(",");
        $("#type-array-id-1").val("");
        $("#type-comma-sep").val(type_array);
    });
</script>
```

I've used some other SO questions answers to get me this far BUT when I submit the form I get:

```
example?type=1%2C2%2C3%2C4
```

My back-end relies on the "," being present in the URL. So how can I force the comma into the URL?

I also tried htaccess rewrite (although not even sure this is right):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^\%2C]*)\%2C(.*)$
RewriteRule .* %1,%2 [R=301,L]
```

And I tried using encodeURIComponent(type_array) and encodeURI(type_array), but it never made a difference.

Also my settings in Codeigniter are as follows:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.,:_\-';
```

And within system/libraries/input.php

```
if ( ! preg_match('/^[a-z0-9,:_\/-]+$/i', $str))
```

So...

1. How can I force the comma in the URL (Javascript is preferable)?
2. Will the solution work cross-browser?

Comment: Does your back-end absolutely have to rely on the comma being present? Can you not use the `$_GET` array directly? Or could you decode the value of `$_GET['type']`?

Comment: No it doesn't have to as I can change it, but my understanding is from a common / good practice URL design then type=1,2,3 is better

Comment: @GregorMcKelvie I've never heard that. I would recommend using a GET array instead of `explode`ing a string.

Comment: The better practice would be to use CodeIgniter's URL scheme and avoid using a query string in the URL: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Comment: @froddd Yeh but I've got potentially up to 10 "types" type=1,2,3,4 etc. plus other dynamic variables that affect the results (as I am using the URL to filter results). So CI's URL scheme is not best for this (IMO).

Comment: How about `$this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n)`? I use it all the time: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: @froddd yeh so in the CI example "user/search/name/joe/location/UK/gender/male" I have 10 locations, 5 names and 5 genders so example?location=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$names=1,2,3,4,5=&genders=1,2,3,4,5 (The URL is behind a login so doesn't need to be SEO friendly - and I think this way is better for REST API if I ever create one). So can't see how this would be beter using CI URL features?

Comment: From your comment: "my understanding is from a common / good practice URL design then type=1,2,3 is better" -- that's true, a cleaner URL is more user-friendly. So why not make it even cleaner: `example/locations/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10/names/1,2,3,4,5/genders/1,2,3,4,5` then use `explode()` on each parameter to create an array? I was merely pointing out that in terms of user-friendliness, you might as well use the built-in URL scheme -- once you get used to these URLs you won't ever want to use a query string again. 

By the way, what are genders 3, 4 and 5? ;)

Comment: @froddd Ha genders 3, 4 and 5 were just to explain my point :) Thanks for the comments - really appreciate it. I'll have a look at doing it the you've suggested. In a way I'm also used to doing it the other way!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16821/discussion-between-froddd-and-gregor-mckelvie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the redirect via Javascript then it should be OK!

```
$("#type-form").bind("submit",function(){
    var type_array = $("#type-array-id-1").val().join(",");

    window.location = '?type='+type_array;

    return false;
});
```

If you let the form submit normally, it'll URL encode all the query string parameters, converting your commas.

If you just explicitly set the URL with the commas, it should work OK (or at least it did in my test example above)!

Comment: No problem! Just keep in mind that you'll have to add manually any other input field data you might have in the form as well (if your form changes from this)